# setInterval после clearInterval

Tags: javascript

имеется такой код:

```
var interval = setInterval(function()
{
// code
// loop
clearInterval(interval )
}, 2000);
```

Как заметно из кода, после выполнения code и loop секции я чищу интервал.
Как обратно вызвать setInterval?

Comment: снова вызвать `setInterval`?)))00

Comment: записать функцию внутри интервала - отдельно, и потом вызхвать еще раз setInterval

Answer (score 0):

```js
function doStuff() {
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
      // code
      // loop
      clearInterval(interval);
      doStuff();
    }, 2000);
}

doStuff();
```